# Problems with Observable.interval - data is not updating in template, ngFor is incorrect length, get polling data on startup

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, rxjs

in my constant struggle to teach myself Angular2 (next time I have vacation days I'm going on vacation!) and I have a problem... I have a servive that pulls user data from a phoney REST service I have created. In my service I wish to poll data (in this case I mock friends who are online and friends who aren't online). Here is the service with the polling code:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDataService {

    public loginInUser: Subject<UserStatus> = new BehaviorSubject<UserStatus>(null);
    public currentUser: UserStatus;
    public onlineContacts: Subject<UserContact> = new BehaviorSubject<UserContact>(null);
    public userContacts: Subject<UserContact> = new BehaviorSubject<UserContact>(null);

    constructor(public http:Http) {
        this.loadUserStatus(); // this is lower in the Component... I have not included it here
        this.pollContacts();
    }

    private pollContacts() : any {

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return Observable.interval(30000)
            .switchMap(() => this.http.get('/restservice/contacts', {headers: headers}))
            //.startWith() - Would this allow me to kick off the service when the Component is loaded / called?
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                data = data.json();
                this.onlineContacts.next(data.onlineContacts);
                this.userContacts.next(data.allContacts);
            });

    }
```

Here is my component that calls the service:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contacts-list',
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: require('./contact-list.html')
})

export class ContactsList {

    public onlineContacts: any;
    public userContacts: any;

    constructor (public userDataService: UserDataService) {
        this.userDataService.onlineContacts.subscribe(
            (onlineContacts) => {
                this.onlineContacts = onlineContacts;
            });

        this.userDataService.userContacts.subscribe(
            (userContacts) => {
                this.userContacts = userContacts;
            });
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML view / template for my component...

```
<h3>Online Contacts</h3>
<div class="online-contact" *ngIf="onlineContacts?.length > 0" *ngFor="#con of onlineContacts" [routerLink]="['ForeignProfile', {id: con.persId}]">
    <img [src]="con.imgUrl" class="img-circle online-contact-img">
    {{ con.name }}
</div>

<h3>Contacts</h3>
<div class="online-contact" *ngIf="userContacts?.length > 0" *ngFor="#con of userContacts" [routerLink]="['ForeignProfile', {id: con.persId}]">
    <img [src]="con.imgUrl" class="img-circle offline-contact-img">
    {{ con.name }}
</div>
```

Now I am beset with problems...

1. firstly I need to kickoff the `pollContacts()` method when the Component / view is loaded rather than wait for the interval to pass. I tried adding the `.startWith` method (see the comment) but I was unsure of the argument to pass to the method?
2. The polling works and the correct information is passed from the service to the Component... however the template is not updating? Do I need to add the `async` pipe to the template (I did try this and it didn't work)?
3. For some reason the two ngFor directives iterate (or loop) one more than the actual length of the object arrays. For example the `*ngFor="#con of onlineContacts"` has two rows (loops two times) when the object array contains only one item and the `*ngFor="#con of userContacts"` has 20 rows (loops 20 times) when there are the length of userContacts is 19!

I realise I am and have been asking a lot of questions on this subject but I have no one to talk to on this subject so please tolerate my questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add the service into your `providers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, yes, you can use the `startWith` operator but it must be used before the `switchMap` one:

```
return Observable.interval(3000)
        .startWith('')
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get('./app/restservice/contacts', {headers: headers}))
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
        });
```

Regarding the `async`, it's up to you. Either you use directly the `subscribe` method either you let the pipe use it under the hood.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <h3>Contacts</h3>
    <div class="online-contact" *ngFor="#con of userContacts | async">
      <img [src]="con.imgUrl" class="img-circle offline-contact-img">
      {{ con.name }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class ContactsList {
  public onlineContacts: any;
  public userContacts: any;

  constructor (public userDataService: UserDataService) {
    this.userContacts = this.userDataService.userContacts;
  }
}
```

Regarding the last point, I have no problem to display data from your `BehaviorSubject`s. Perhaps there is a problem at the level of your data. Do you receive something like that:

```
{
  "allContacts": [
    {
      "name": "Sparky",
      "imgUrl": "https://restlet.com/static/app/img/sparky_right.png"
    }
  ],
  "onlineContacts": [
    {
      "name": "Sparky",
      "imgUrl": "https://restlet.com/static/app/img/sparky_right.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/vYQPePG4KDoktPoGaxYu?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks for that, but moving the `.startWith('')` seems to produce the error `'error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps you could try `0` instead of `''` for the parameter of the `startWith` operator...

Comment: I tried that too... It just resulted in `EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`errors... I am looking into that now

Comment: That's strange because the parameter you provide isn't use within the following `switchMap`. Where does the error occur? On the `data.json()`?

Comment: No! It does work, there was an issue with the Rest Service... although the view isn't updating from the null state to the populated state

Comment: Great! Could you check if the `subscribe` methods are called in your component and if so, which values are received as parameters?

Comment: When using `console.log(this.userContacts, userContacts);` & console.log(this.onlineContacts, onlineContacts); in the subscribe() callbacks after we assign the local property with the argument (or what is passed back) everything is updating in the component... however the template / view remains the same...

Comment: Could you try to remove the `ngIf` at the level of the `ngFor`? I heard that this doesn't work very well (`ngIf` and `ngFor` on the same element)...

Comment: No, removing those makes no difference

Comment: Got it working! Thanks! I still had `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the component and that seemed to prevent the change!

Comment: Great! Yes, with `OnPush`, you need to explicitly tell to Angular2 that there is a change so it can update the view... You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to explicitly notify Angular about changes:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'contacts-list',
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: require('./contact-list.html'),
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // <== added (optional)
})

export class ContactsList {

    public onlineContacts: any;
    public userContacts: any;

    constructor (public userDataService: UserDataService,
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef // <== added
    ) {
        this.userDataService.onlineContacts.subscribe(
            (onlineContacts) => {
                this.onlineContacts = onlineContacts;
                this.cd.markForCheck(); // <== added
            });

        this.userDataService.userContacts.subscribe(
            (userContacts) => {
                this.userContacts = userContacts;
                this.cd.markForCheck(); // <== added
            });
    }
}
```

See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Thanks for that, however all I get now is an error `EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of ContactsList!. ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeDetector' of null`

Comment: Did you add `ChangeDetectorRef` to the list of imported classes from `angular2/core`?

Comment: I sure did...`import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core';`

Comment: I guess you changed `cd` (from my answer) to `changeDetector` (in your application code). I have no idea what causes the error. https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html contains an link to a Plunker (live demo) with a simple example similar to my answer.

Comment: I haven't a clue where it's getting 'changeDetector' from as I used the name cd you provided?

Comment: I just had the same error. `ChangeDetectorRef ` seems to haven't been instanciated yet. To solve it, just move your 2 `subscribe` functions inside `onInit` hook (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html).